# Syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: mysql

```
$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host_name, $username, $password, $database);

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM pembeli");
$hasil = mysqli_query($query);

while ( $buyer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil)){
    echo $buyer ['Nama'];
    echo $buyer ['Barang'];
    echo $buyer ['Retribusi'];
}
```

I have that line of code, its produce syntax error unexpected '$query'(T_VARIABLE). Whats wrong ?

Comment: So you put the result of `mysqli_query` in another `mysqli_query`???

Comment: so, what must i write?

Comment: I suggest you take some time to research mysqli basics(, and spend a little time on code formatting). You're making a few odd mistakes, some research will allow you to find your own mistake in this case.

Comment: Apart from that, we're not a site that 'just gives you the answer'

Comment: @jakaperdana Please add the full error message to your question. Also add the full source code of the mentioned PHP file to your question. To not alter/change the source code besides removing the login data.

Comment: @jakaperdana You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/15539535#15539535.

Answer (score 1):

**In mysqli no need to write :-** `mysql_select_db($database);`

**because fourth param in is database name**

**example :-** `mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $database);`

**Update your code as shown below**

```
$database  = "jaka_crud_ci";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host_name, $username, $password, $database);

$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT * FROM pembeli");

while ( $buyer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $buyer['Nama'];
    echo $buyer['Barang'];
    echo $buyer['Retribusi'];
}
```